# Odoo switches pages when they become visible

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I added additional pages (tabs) to a form view. Also I have a boolean field. For example.: lets say at view_partner_form when I click is a customer = True, additional page I added next to sales and purchases becomes visible. The problem is that odoo opens that pages that became visible. I don't want that, I consider it bug. I want to stay at Sales and Purchases.

If there is anyone with similar problems please share your solution.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you add the page left to Sales and Purchases?

Comment: To the right sight. That might be important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a possibility to use the autofocus in the XML.

Example

```xml
<page autofocus="autofocus">
    <field name="customer"/>
        ...
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this method seems to be working so far.